# Why does the output come undefined when I'm trying to reverse a string?- javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reverse a string using javascript. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id = "test"></p>    
    <script>
      var a = prompt("Enter anything to reverse", "Type Here");
      var b;
      var c;
      var d = a.length;
      for (i=d;i>=1;i--){
        b = a.substr(i,1);
        c = c + b;
      };
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "The reverse is " + c;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the output is `undefined`. Please help!

Comment: 1) initialize c (var c = ""); 2) Arrays are 0 indexed (for(i = d-1;i>=0;i--))

Comment: please explain as answer!

Comment: You need to initialize the variable c. In your for loop, you can't add c as it doesn't have anything related to it, and that is where your code breaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) In doing `var c;` it is `undefined`, so `c = c + b` is doing `undefined` + char

2) Arrays are 0 indexed, so you should begin at `length - 1` and end at index 0.

Here is working version :

```js
var a = prompt("Enter anything to reverse", "Type Here");
var b;
var c = "";
var d = a.length;
for (i= d - 1;i >= 0;i--){
  b = a.substr(i,1);
  c = c + b;
};
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "The reverse is " + c;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id = "test"></p>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understood why I should have ended at 0 but why should it start from length -1?

Comment: If you have 'hello', h is on index 0 and o is on index 4, if you use string[string.length] it will result in null or undefined, as the length is 5 and that is past the last character

Comment: OH. Now I understand.Thanks!

Comment: @uvrichest no problem, feel free to mark one of the answers as accepted if your issue has been resolved

Answer (score 1):

To reverse a string, first `split()` it into an array, `reverse()` the array then `join()` the array to rebuild the string

```
return a.split("").reverse().join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="test"></p>
  <script>
    var a = prompt("Enter anything to reverse", "Type Here");
    var b;
    var c = '';
    var d = a.length;
    console.log(d)
    for (i = d - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      b = a.substr(i, 1);
      c += b;
    };
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "The reverse is " + c;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like someone said in the comments, you need to initialize your variable c. You also need to start at `a.length-1`.

```js
var a = prompt("Enter anything to reverse", "Type Here");
var b;
var c = "";
var d = a.length-1;
for (i = d; i >= 0; i--) {
  b = a.substr(i, 1);
  c = c + b;
};
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "The reverse is " + c;
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
```

But there's a simpler solution to this:

```js
var a = prompt("Enter anything to reverse", "Type Here");
var c = a.split("").reverse().join("");
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "The reverse is " + c;
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
```